# How and why was my Stack Exchange profile changed without my knowledge or permission?

Tags: support, profile-page, privacy

I just took a look at my Stack Exchange profile, and it had been modified to include my professional title and employer company name in the "title" field.

I had not set this data and log in using my Google account, which does not contain this information publicly, and has no business being in the "title" field in any case.

I am not at all happy about this.  My activity on this site is not related to my employment, and this is information that I would not wish to provide to users of this site.

I have since restored the original information.

Comment: Did you join into an Stack Overflow Team? As explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/teams

Comment: I see you joined the  site Computer Science last month. I've had an incident before where my real name all of a sudden became my display_name when I joined a site.

Comment: @rene : If that is the answer, then it is even more insidious.  I in fact never joined that site (not intentionally).  A question I answered on Stack Overflow was migrated to.  I have deleted my profile from that site.

Comment: @rene : Re. SO for Teams - no.

Comment: Let's keep it at that magic happens when you join (intentionally or not) a site.

Comment: I have checked my Google profile and it contained both my LinkedIn profile address and my employment details, but these were not set to public.  I don't recall even setting them - thanks Google, but nonetheless the profile information on SO should not have changed.

Comment: I checked and I believe something similar happened to [this account of mine](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/8469/rene?tab=profile) which I sadly only reported in [chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3442653#3442653) and it doesn't look like any SE dev responded to that which they sometimes do. So this is all I have. Sorry.

Comment: @user1114 ;  That is missing the point somewhat;  I am not asking _where_ the information came from, but rather how and why it is used inappropriately here. 1) The information was not marked _public_.  2) Stack Overflow has no field for "employer name", the content was placed in the "title" field.  I dare say, Google acquired the information from LinkedIn where it is appropriately public - but not to be passed on to unrelated accounts..

Comment: @user1114 : Thanks; that information appears to be about non-public SO profile information.  In my case, the _public_ information was modified.  Apart from the fact that I would not have entered this information myself, the company name was out-of-date following a name change a couple of years ago - I certainly did not enter _old_ information, and it was not there at least a couple of months ago.

Comment: @user1114 : I provided Google my linked in profile (probably - I don;t recall).  I perhaps should have been aware that they might use public information from there to complete my Google profile, but the terms are TL;DR, but the Google profile "copy" was not public.  I would expect the right to decide where and in what context or platforms I make information public.  I am not accusing Google of anything w.r.t. my Google profile - SO will have pulled that information from somewhere - and it remains insidious and inappropriate, however it happend.